# xampp mysql user works only without password

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm developing a PHP/MySQL site locally using XAMPP.
In my PHP connection file I had a user 'root' with an empty password, and it worked fine so far.
However when I try to add a new **user** in XAMPP **with a password** (that matches the live site configuration), the **site stops working**, producing 500 error.
I tried and checked everything, but I couldn't figure out what the problem could be.
What should I still check?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Locate phpMyAdmin installation path.

Step 2:
Open phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php in your favourite text editor. Copy config.sample.inc.php to  config.inc.php if it's missing.

Step 3:
Search for $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';

Replace it with $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';